# What'd be the more common equivalent to Tolkien's "the young perish and the old linger"?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

> The young perish and the old linger, withering.
> <sup>*[The Two Towers](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Two_Towers/12e8PJ2T7sQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The%20young%20perish%20and%20the%20old%20linger,%20withering%22&pg=PT74&printsec=frontcover)* by J.R.R. Tolkien</sup>

Is there a common English phrase for when an old person, unfortunately, watches a young person die before them, even though the old one wishes it were the other way around?

For example, imagine a grandma watches her beloved grandchild die because of an incurable disease.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that there is a ***real*** phrase and that Tolkien’s is some cheap imitation?

Comment: @Jim It's a quote from a ***fiction*** book. Maybe that's why it's not "real". And did I say anything about "cheap imitation"?

Comment: I guess I thought it was implied when you referred to his quote and then implied that there was a ***real*** one.  Also i’ve never encountered that sentiment before. What I have encountered are things like “No patent should have to outlive their children” which says quite the opposite.  In fact it seems like the proportion of people older than you that you have to see die is always going to be larger than the number of people younger than you.

Comment: "Only the good die young" is in the same ballpark, but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to say or what situation you're referring to. It's obviously not true that everybody dies young, so who specifically dies young or lives to be old?

Comment: @Jim I'd like to say that there was absolutely no need to immediately assume ill will from an innocuous question. I'm not here to piss off the Tolkien fandom by questioning his originality. It's just that in my language there's actually a saying that conveys the exact spirit of that quote, and I wanted to know if there's a genuinely used saying like that in English. There's a different between "so help me God", which is from the Bible and which is **actually** used, and "to be or not to be", which is only used when you want to invoke Shakespeare.

Comment: "To be or not to be" is also invoked when a person is making a difficult decision, it's not only used when citing Shakespeare's Hamlet. But you're right to imagine that Tolkein's expression is uncommon in spoken English.

Comment: No. That’s presumably why Tolkien expressed it in an individual manner. Others have done likewise using different words. As this is not an English Literature site I am spared the embarrassment of not being able to think of an example, but if TS Elliott didn’t, he should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The young perish and the old linger, withering.

Some consider this to be   a [personal commentary on World War II](https://dc.swosu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1264&context=mythlore)

As you may recall, both of Tolkien's sons were combatants  in the war. It seems that as a worried parent  he was possibly making a personal comment about the unjust toll taken upon the youth of the world during war...so I will answer in the same vein *with a qualification...*

---

****...Unless*** you are looking for a more common phrase* as used in cases of fatalities from accident or child-hood disease...

> "No parent should have to bury their child."

...which ironically also comes from Tolkien (King Theoden) and is more well-known.

---

...***I am offering*** a few suggestions:

“War is young men dying and old men talking”  -FDR

“I'm fed up to the ears with old men dreaming up wars for young men to die in.” -George McGovern

"Old soldiers never die, they just fade away" -General Douglas MacArthur

---

***But for me,*** the most significant comment comes from a long forgotten poem...

If I were fierce, and bald, and short of breath, ...
I'd live with scarlet Majors at the Base,
And speed glum heroes up the line to death.
You'd see me with my puffy petulant face,
Guzzling and gulping in the best hotel,
Reading the Roll of Honour. "Poor young chap,"
I'd say—"I used to know his father well;
Yes, we've lost heavily in this last scrap."
***And when the war is done and youth stone dead,

I'd toddle safely home and die—in bed.***

*Base Details* by Siegfried Sasoon (1917)

---

All of that said, ***the original from Tolkien is almost poetry***; and like most poetry it is wide-open for interpretation.

Comment: ...but this sounds like LitCrit.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a common English phrase for when an old person, unfortunately, watches a young person die before them, even though the old one wishes it were the other way around?

Reading all of the above, it appears that the answer is *"No, there isn't."*

There is nothing more than phrases, some common, some good, some bad that express the emotion of such an event.

Comment: Dude, don't just base your answer on other people's comments just to get points. The bounty specifically looks for an answer with a reputable source. If you don't have one, but you're convinced that there's no such phrase, just leave a comment.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw Dude, sometimes, the answer **is** that there is no answer. A point worth remembering is that students of English often look for a word or phrase that exists in their own language/culture or that they think should exist in English.

Comment: I'm aware that there may not be an answer, so after my question was changed to "more common equivalent", I decided to go ahead with the bounty, may be I'll get a catchier phrase from literature even if it's not "real", or maybe all I'll get is Tolkien.

Comment: I'm emphasizing the "Reading all of the above", which is the sole basis of your entire answer, which is not the point of the bounty. You haven't shown you did any research at all. I'm not asking you to look for something that doesn't exist, but at least something like "I was an English major and I've never encountered a phrase like Tolkien's in any of the books I've read" would be more helpful.

Comment: I am curious to know "reading all of the above", which encompasses and includes the experiences of all those who wrote, might be less than "I've never encountered a phrase like Tolkien's in any of the books I've read"; especially when you realise that I must be including my experience too.

Comment: I myself am capable of "reading all of the above" too, as with literally every literate English speaker on Earth. I hope you agree that "the above" is *not* an authoritative source. If all I needed was "the above", this bounty would be completely pointless. If you trust in your experience as someone well-versed in English literature and authoritative enough to give an opinion, do use it in your answer, because "reading all of the above" and "it appears" are only your dubious speculation alone, and undoubtedly and obviously less than citing a single book you've read.